# How can I delete noise level of the speakers?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am developing an app that measures noise with Flutter.
I have already developed this function using the MaxAmplitude of the microphone and converting this in Decibel, but I'd like to try to run this function when the speakers are going and the noise caused from them it should not affect noise levels.
How can I delete noise level of the speakers?